# how to neglect case sensitivity in os.rename replace

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a script that replaces file names with a new filename that I specify, however, right now it is case sensitive (if a filename = DM, but I enter Dm, it is not being replaced)

I already tried filename.lower(), in the os.rename, but it doesn't seem to work. There are no errors though, that filename remains unaltered though.

```py
import os

old = 'dm'
new = 'datamining'

path = os.getcwd()

filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename ( path+'\\'+ filename.lower() , path+'\\'+ filename.replace(old , new) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual file names are not necessarily in lowercase, but you're passing to the `replace` method a lowercase string of `'dm'`. It cannot find the lowercase `'dm'` in the file name and therefore returns the same file name, resulting in `os.rename` doing nothing.

You can lowercase the file name before you call the `replace` method instead:

```
os.rename( path+'\\'+ filename , path+'\\'+ filename.lower().replace(old , new) )
```

This will force the new file name to be entirely in lowercase, however. If you want to preserve the casing of the rest of the file names, you can use `re.sub` with the `IGNORECASE` flag instead:

```
import re

...

os.rename( path+'\\'+ filename , path+'\\'+ re.sub(old, new, filename, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```